# Output json "Array of Objects" to sink inside an Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a source file in a Storage account that is json "Document per line". I transform it through a Data Flow and would like the outpout to a json file to be an array of objects(e.g. actually valid json format).
Source file:

```json
{..}
{..}
{..}
```

Expected output (array of objects):

```json
[
{},
{},
{}
]
```

The sink in a Data Flow doesn't have any options to specify the desired output. Do anyone have any idea in how to achieve this?

My current effort consists of selecting "Output to single file" in the Sink settings. But there are no options for selecting json format.
[image: sink settings]

Comment: Is not even valid under RFC 8259

Answer (score 3):

I fixed by sinking into a csv (everything will be set to string), adjusted every column with `coalesce` (because it would create null values) and used copy data to transform to json.
In the sink tab of the copy data, set the `File Pattern` to `Array of Objects`

[image]